# "[Noun] as she is [past participle]"

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions, connotation

As an example, I recently came across a blog titled "Software As She Is Developed". I know I've seen that construct before — "*noun* as she is *past participle*" — in other contexts. It's fairly self-explanatory, but a quirky way of phrasing it. What exactly does it connote, and does it have a specific origin?

Comment: The blog's actually called [Software As She’s Developed](http://softwareas.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [snowclone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) derived from the title of the unspeakably bad text [*English as She Is Spoke*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke).

Comment: Bad, maybe, but not exactly unspeakable.

Comment: Rather than a 'snowclone derived from', it is actually 'derived from the snowclone'.   

"English as she is spoke" is the snowclone spawning quirky sentences like the one here.

Comment: @Kris: From the linked Wikipedia article: "The term 'snowclone' can be applied to both the original phrase and to any new phrase that uses its formula".

Comment: @RegDwight Yes, I know they 'can be'. However, doing so here would defeat the purpose.  We want to draw attention to the original, while also introducing the term 'snowclone'.

Comment: So is it always used ironically, as if to say "this isn't really the way it should be done"?

Answer (score 1):

Check out "English as she is spoke."  You may find very interesting info.

Your example sentence takes off on this classic usage of 'as she is'.